# Parse Keeps Crashing my android when keeps crashing my app when trying to login - "unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject"

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to hunt down the cause and find a work around (I'm pretty sure it's a bug in PARSE)

So...
I'm using Parse on Android -
with local data store enabled.
Automatic users ( I have also non automatic users )
and default acl for permission

When I start the app offline and play around for a while at some point the application would start crashing at some point.
I guessing it has somthing to do with local data store & user auth since it didn't happen to me online or if I went offline after first usage.

```
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959): 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.PointerEncodingStrategy.encodeRelatedObject(PointerEncodingStrategy.java:22)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.Parse.encode(Parse.java:641)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParseACL.toJSONObject(ParseACL.java:85)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.Parse.encode(Parse.java:677)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParseSetOperation.encode(ParseSetOperation.java:19)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.Parse.encode(Parse.java:724)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParseObject.toJSONObjectForSaving(ParseObject.java:1239)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParseObject.constructSaveCommand(ParseObject.java:1126)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParseObject.saveAsync(ParseObject.java:1423)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParsePinningEventuallyQueue$13.then(ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.java:471)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParsePinningEventuallyQueue$13.then(ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.java:462)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:477)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:349)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:360)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:406)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:398)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:477)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:349)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:398)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:418)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.process(ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.java:462)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.waitForOperationSetAndEventuallyPin(ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.java:433)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParsePinningEventuallyQueue$10.then(ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.java:326)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at com.parse.ParsePinningEventuallyQueue$10.then(ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.java:323)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:477)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:473)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:349)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:360)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:406)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:398)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:477)
12-14 06:26:34.267: E/ParsePinningEventuallyQueue(22959):   at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
```